# ORDER BY not working as expected with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, left-join

I have two tables, establishment and branch. Establishment is the parent table. When I select a list of branches, I want it to retrieve the establishment name if the branch title is blank. Also, I only want to show a branch once for each establishment. This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT 
  branch.id
  , branch.establishment_ID
  , IFNULL(branch.branch_title, establishment.name) AS branch_title 
FROM branch 
LEFT JOIN establishment ON branch.establishment_ID = establishment.id 
WHERE cityID = 2 
GROUP BY establishment_ID 
ORDER BY branch_title
```

However, the results do not appear to be in any particular order. I want them to be in alphabetical order. I've read that MySQL 5.0.5 had problems with GROUP BY and ORDER BY in the same query, but I'm working with 5.5.9. What can I do to fix this query?

Comment: The group by is indeterminate. That's your problem, The whole query does not make sense and therefor it mixes data from unrelated rows.

Comment: You're not using any aggregate functions for branch.id and establishment_id. When there are multiple establishmentids or branch ids, you need to supply an aggregate function (e.g. max) to determine which ones are selected when you group.

Comment: You're selecting 3, non-aggregates, branch.id, branch.establishment_ID, branch_title, but grouping by just one of them(which is not valid, though mysql doesn't complain). You should group by all 3 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess (knowing other SQL systems) that your `ORDER BY` is applying to `branch.branch_title`, rather than to your new alias. Are you able to copy your `IFNULL()` expression into the `ORDER BY`?

```
SELECT 
  branch.id
  , branch.establishment_ID
  , IFNULL(branch.branch_title, establishment.name) AS branch_title 
FROM branch 
LEFT JOIN establishment ON branch.establishment_ID = establishment.id 
WHERE cityID = 2 
GROUP BY establishment_ID 
ORDER BY IFNULL(branch.branch_title, establishment.name)
```

Otherwise, the `NULL` branch_title rows will always appear (before/after) the non-`NULL` ones, and will not be sorted in any way.

Comment: yep, use the expression not the alias because it is ambiguous

Comment: Simply write `ORDER BY 3` to use the value of output column 3. Better yet, use a **different name** for the computed `branch_title` to avoid such mistakes. BTW, another potential problem with `GROUP BY establishment_ID`. Can be ambiguos, too. Especially as you have a `LEFT JOIN`on it. qualify the name (`branch.establishment_ID`) or substitute `GROUP BY 2`.